# Minecraft Fabric: 'net.minecraft.util.Identifier net.minecraft.util.registry.RegistryKey.method_29177()'

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I launched fabric 1.18.2 template from official repository.

**I use java 17 (adopt open jdk, tried to use open-jdk).**

Error i get:

```
[19:46:05] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Mixin) SpongePowered MIXIN Subsystem Version=0.8.5 Source=file:/home/wartuu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.fabricmc/sponge-mixin/0.11.2+mixin.0.8.5/f4ae569d559b5e3244b67321945261d83ff7ad8e/sponge-mixin-0.11.2+mixin.0.8.5.jar Service=Knot/Fabric Env=CLIENT
[19:46:05] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Mixin) Loaded Fabric development mappings for mixin remapper!
[19:46:05] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Mixin) Compatibility level set to JAVA_16
[19:46:05] [main/INFO] (FabricLoader/Mixin) Compatibility level set to JAVA_17
[19:46:06] [main/ERROR] (FabricLoader) Minecraft has crashed!
 net.fabricmc.loader.impl.FormattedException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'net.minecraft.util.Identifier net.minecraft.util.registry.RegistryKey.method_29177()'
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:418) ~[fabric-loader-0.13.3.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:77) [fabric-loader-0.13.3.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23) [fabric-loader-0.13.3.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'net.minecraft.util.Identifier net.minecraft.util.registry.RegistryKey.method_29177()'
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.SimpleRegistry.handler$zbf000$setPre(SimpleRegistry.java:651) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.SimpleRegistry.set(SimpleRegistry.java) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.SimpleRegistry.set(SimpleRegistry.java:86) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.SimpleRegistry.add(SimpleRegistry.java:134) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.create(Registry.java:354) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.create(Registry.java:346) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.create(Registry.java:330) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry.<clinit>(Registry.java:185) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:49) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:153) ~[minecraft-project-@-merged-named.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:416) ~[fabric-loader-0.13.3.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run in terminal :

1. ./gradlew clean
2. ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies

Then reload gradle project in 'Gradle' tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32188937)